How to solve :ImportError: dlopen(/.../XXX.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_gsl_sf_gamma'"
When I run a function in a python package, it returns:
import gala.potential as gp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gala/potential/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .potential import *
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gala/potential/potential/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .cpotential import *
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gala/potential/potential/cpotential.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_gsl_sf_gamma'

As the error message contains "_gsl_sf_gamma", so I suppose the problem is coming from the GSL library of C/C++.
I am using Mac with M2 Chip. I have installed GSL before by homebrew, so the path of GSL is
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1

Moreover, I have also installed gcc before by homebrew.
However, the default gcc is installed from Xcode, which uses clang and its path is
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

I suppose the problem is from the inconsistency between the GSL and the gcc.
I have tried to reinstall GSL through conda (without uninstall the previous GSL), but it doesn't work.

A few questions: does the file /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gala/potential/potential/cpotential.cpython-311-darwin.so exist? Does it correspond to the current site-package for your python? Does the error contain the same file when you use conda, or a different one?

@tbrugere Thank you for your answer. Yes, the file cpotential.cpython-311-darwin.so in that path do exist, and it corresponds to the site-package for the python I used. I tried to use conda only for installing GSL, but I used the same python which is installed by homebrew, maybe that is the reason it does not work? Moreover, I am confused with the different directories in /opt/homebrew: there are python3 and python3.11 in /opt/homebrew/bin and in /opt/homebrew/opt, while in /opt/homebrew/lib there are python3.10, python 3.11 and python3.12, what are their relations?

Furthermore, there is another directory /opt/homebrew/Cellar, and it only has python@3.11. Why different directories have different numbers of python version?

what happens if you use the python from the conda env you installed GSL in?

@tbrugere I created a conda env and installed Python and GSL, and now it works! Thank you for your advice. By the way, could you explain the different directories and different versions in the homebrew? Although now I can use the package in the conda, I haven't understood the cause of the failure outside the conda.

Sure, I'll write an answer explaining what I believe is happening

OK so this is a linking problem.
The library you  are trying to import tries to call a function _gsl_sf_gamma (probably from the GSL library) but cannot find it.
The library you are trying to import is programmed in a compiled language (most likely C or C++). In these languages, libraries, work a bit differently from how they work in python. There are two ways to get functions or other values reffered to by names (symbols) from a library.

Static linking bundles the function from the library in the binary calling it.
Dynamic linking loads the library on-demand, like python does with its import statement. It is more complicated because the binary calling the function needs to find the library somewhere on the system.

So basically something was not properly linked. Probably that that cpotential.cpython-311-darwin.so expects the GSL library to already be dynamically loaded.
Now the conda environment changes a bunch of things, including where programs are going to look for dynamically linked libraries. It probably loaded a different version of cpotential.cpython-311-darwin.so which loaded GSL correctly from conda's libraries

Thank you very much for your detailed answer! So that means when calling for the function from the GSL library, it cannot find the GSL library. Does it relate to the problem with PATH? Is there any way I can confirm the cause?

Probably not with PATH, but with DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH
